# Hebrew text disappears from PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I have a PDF with a form inside (the PDF was created with master pdf creator). I'm using Python's `fillpdf` library to populate the values, at this stage everything is OK, except some applications show the text flipped. The main issue occurs when I'm creating a "flattened" version, where all the Hebrew text disappears.

Under the hood, the library uses `pdfindo`, but I can't understand what went wrong.

The code is simply:

```
fillpdfs.write_fillable_pdf("test.pdf", "output1.pdf", {"test": "מידע בעברית"})
fillpdfs.flatten_pdf("output1.pdf", "output2.pdf", as_images=True)
```

**Update**:

looks like the underlining usage of `pdftoppm` omits the characters:

```
$ pdftoppm -r 200 test.pdf -f 1 -l 5 > /dev/null
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05DB
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05D0
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05DF
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05E8
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05E9
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05D5
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05DD
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05DE
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05E9
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05D4
Syntax Error: AnnotWidget::layoutText, cannot convert U+05D5
```

using a file filled on third party vendor ([www.sejda.com](https://www.sejda.com)) managed to produce a readable file

Comment: This looks like a bug report for fillpdf, why not send it directly to them?

Comment: Sound like your update is an answer to your question

Comment: @Soleil, this doesn't explain what cause the problem and how to fix it. only that it looks like the encoding is wrong and can be ok. but still, what is the correct one (encoding?), and how can it be forced?

Comment: Where do you expect the font with the hebrew characters to be found from? If the annotations are to be flattened, they will need a font with the approriate characters to be embedded in the PDF. Perhaps the font used by your software does not have the hebrew characters.

Comment: @johnwhitington I've checked the fonts, although the font is not embedded, the image creator can load them (probably from the system). that was my reasoning to check with the 3rd party vendor, which used the same base PDF file

Answer (score 0):

AcroForms are now three decades old and thus not much has been allowed to alter that legacy approach, or old forms would fail! If it works (revenue wise) dont change it.

So how do forms work in general is, they were "Get" by mime disposition. Modern day that is spam/email or download with without user display. Then user uses keyboard to fill. and after that they "Post" a mime disposition of the forms data to a nominated post box (server).

How that data is transferred can be one of 2 methods or a combination.
Here just the data is imported. Equally a user could press a submit button to export just the data to the mime server.

[image]

Enough of the history, so what is required in that import export? Here it is, and we can see the core problem. Whilst most data would be plain ANSI for Anglo-American form data, it needs to be 16bit encoded for more international content. And that cross format encoding needs to be imbedded inside the form.

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/F (hebrew.pdf)
/Fields [<<
/T (Dobby)
/V (9/10/61)
>> <<
/T (FirstName)
/V (þÿÙÕáã)
>> <<
/T (LastName)
/V (þÿÛÔß)
>> <<
/T (MiddleName)
/V (þÿÞÐÙè)
>>]
/UF (hebrew.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

So by opening the FDF in Adobe Desktop Acrobat Reader(/Writer) the data can also be exported as a whole PDF and the other readers that are NOT forms enabled can see the flattened version, but a side effect is the 16bit content accessible in Acrobat as text (see box on the left)is not accessible after pdf flattening (see notepad extraction on right) via adding fields (also that header is inaccessible too, but that is for a different reason).

[image]

What Adobe Acrobat sees after filling is oddly limited but doubled ! !

[image]